# Insert component inside html

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to add a render of a component inside a `<a>` balise.

I have one component :

```
import Tableau from "./tableauCOlonnes.jsx";

class Views_Default_Mapping extends React.Component {
    render() {
    var liste_colonnes = ["Nom", "Age", "Taille"];
    const html = 

    return (

        <div className="div_mapping">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="data:text/html,<Tableau liste_colonnes={liste_colonnes}>" target="tabcontent">Fichier 1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
    );
}
}
```

So I want to add `<Tableau />` with a props inside a `<a>` but it doesn't work. I also tried with html-to-react but I don't know how to do, it doesn't work either. How should I do please ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you mean by "I want to add `<Tableau />` with a props inside a `<a>`"? If you want to render one element inside another, it should be inside the tag, i.e. its children: `<a href="..."><Tableau ... /></a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href={<Tableau liste_colonnes={liste_colonnes}>} target="tabcontent">
    Fichier 1
</a>
```

Comment: I don't have any error but it display all the page inside the frame :/ Like the page inside the page